# How to tab into Task bars in XFCE

Tags: taskbar, xfce

I have two task bars (using MX linux), bar 1 is horizontal on bottom of desktop, bar 2 is vertical on the left of the screen.

I cannot figure out how to tab onto and scroll through the taskbars using keyboard.

Does anyone know?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: XFCE is a graphical interface. I am using it here. I have tried every reasonable combination of keys ending in Tab and XFCE does not recognize it - that is, no way to tab onto the XFCE task bar. I think you will have to use a mouse.

Comment: Thank you for your reply John. I appreciate your efforts. I am however disappointed in your findings, nevertheless I will accept defeat lol. All the best.